# How interchangeable are Redis HASH Key and Field?

Tags: redis

I'm planning to use Redis hashes as map of maps in the following way:
`[version ->[key -> serialized data]]`

Application and data design suggest using Redis `key` as version and Redis `field` as key. In our case that would mean storing only a few dozens of Redis keys with tens of millions fields each.

Seems asymmetrical to the use case scenarios from Redis documentation. Is it okay in terms of performance for simple get/set/delete operations? No key expiration and other Redis advanced techniques will be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly use the Hash data structure to store your data this way. This design adds an additional operation to get/set the value of each field compared to just using simple KV strings (i.e. `version:key` as key and `data` as value). OTOH, by using simple String KV, you'll end up having a lot (few dozens times tens of millions) keys, each having an overhead greater than the approach you've suggested (more on the same at http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization#using-hashes-to-abstract-a-very-memory-efficient-plain-key-value-store-on-top-of-redis).

That said, the Hash approach is valid and used extensively. The performance lost due to the extra operations is usually negligible, especially considering the savings in space.

Note: your question does not specify why/how you need to fetch the serialized data. Do you need to fetch all the keys under a given version? Maybe all the versions of a given key? Both? Other? Depending on your use case's requirements, there may be better alternatives.

Comment: Hi and thanks! Speaking of the usage, I will only need to a) count all the keys for a given version and b) delete all the data (keys and serialized objects) for a version. No key traversing, search operations and such.

Comment: Counting is cheap with Hashes, but be weary of deleting large Hashes - lot any object (Sets, Sorted Sets and Lists), deletion will take longer the bigger that the object is